# Next.js: fetching data in getInitialProps(): server-side vs client-side

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, next.js

I'm using Next.js, and I have a custom server using Express. I have a page that requires some data from the database.

`getInitialProps()`, when running on the server, could just grab the data from the database and return it, without any problems.
However, `getInitialProps()` can also run on the client side (when the user initially requests a different page, then navigates to this one). In that case, since I'm on the client side, I obviously can't just fetch the data from the database - I have to use AJAX to talk to the server and ask it to retrieve it for me.

Of course, this also means that I have define a new Express route on the server to handle this request, which will contain exactly the same code as the server-side part of `getInitialProps()`, which is very undesirable.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since no good solution seemed to have existed, I have created and published a library to provide a simple and elegant solution to this problem: [next-express](https://github.com/shdnx/next-express).

Answer (score 33):

`getInitialProps()` always receives the request and response as parameters which are only set on the server:

```
static async getInitialProps({req}){
 if(req){
   // called on server
 } else {
   // called on client
 }
}
```

https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle

Comment: I do know that, but that does not address my problem.

Comment: If i do my api calls in the server and not in the client as per the solution, will it causes any issue ? And why does getInitialProps() gets called twice, on server and on client ?

Comment: Since `getInitialProps` runs sometimes in the browser as well, make sure never to have secret code in it, even in the `if(req)` clause

Answer (score 6):

In your `getInitialProps` you should be making a http request to a new express route that has your logic for fetching from the database. That logic should never live in the UI layer.

This route should then be called regardless of whether you are on the client or on the server - you don't need to do any code branching.

Answer (score 4):

Make an API distinct from your next.js app. Think of the next app as a frontend client that happens to render pages on the server

Answer (score 4):

With time new solutions come around.

Nextjs has introduced a new method [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) primarily for such use cases

```
getServerSideProps only runs on server-side and never runs on the browser.
```

Comment: getServerSideProps(), seems to be available only after next 9.3.0, i am using 9.0.2 and stuck with getInitialProps(). Is there a work around ?

Comment: @Vishu you should be able to upgrade your version, it'd be better to use them as it'll be a long term solution

Answer (score 1):

For me, the quickest way I found is to get the data from `__NEXT_DATA__`

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (): Promise<AppCustomProps> => {
  const isInBroswer = typeof window !== 'undefined';
  if (isInBroswer) {
    const appCustomPropsString =
      document.getElementById('__NEXT_DATA__')?.innerHTML;

    if (!appCustomPropsString) {
      throw new Error(`__NEXT_DATA__ script was not found`);
    }

    const appCustomProps = JSON.parse(appCustomPropsString).props;
    return appCustomProps;
  }

// server side, where I actually fetch the data from db/cms and return it
}
```